# Win 10 Universal App Project Creation Error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

I've been keen to start developing Windows 10 apps for a while now, but I found things to be a little to unknown and unstable in the near past. With a release date official and Windows 10 making some great progress I've been trying to create a Universal App. However, I receive the following error when loading any Universal app - doesn't matter if it's Visual Basic, C# or C++ I receive the same error and the Project Solution doesn't seem right.

Error:

[image: Error img]

Project Solution:

[image]

My understanding is that the universal apps should have a Windows Phone Project and a Windows Desktop project at least? But as you can see after this error Visual Studio isn't creating these two projects...

Can anyone help?

-Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Build 10130

-All features of Visual Studio are Installed, even the Android SDK ect

-Tried a reinstall of Visual Studio, issue still persisted.

Comment: under advanced option during VS2015 setup, select the Win10 dev tools

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft describes, you have to [do the following steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721%28v=vs.8.5%29.aspx) to install all Windows 10 tools during Visual Studio 2015 RC:

- Select **Custom** install
- Expand Universal Windows app development tools
- Select Tools and Windows SDK 10.0.10069
- Click **Next** to continue and follow the prompts to complete the installation

[image]