# how to port app over to Universal App?

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2015. I read it has a Universal App thing that allows you to write the application once and can be used on multiple platforms. So what do we do if we have a existing project and want to port it over to a universal app? I've searched for hours and I can not find steps on how to port over existing projects to universal apps. Ideas?

Comment: Please check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683804/win-10-universal-app-project-creation-error

Comment: thanks but telling me how to install it does not tell me how to port an existing project over to a universal app.

Comment: What is your project type ?

Comment: You can check the official document: [Porting apps to Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/index). And for existing Desktop Applications, you may check [Project Centennial: Bringing Existing Desktop Applications to the Universal Windows Platform](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B829).